# Cannot resolve symbol `FileUtils` in Codepath `Todo App` tutorial (Android)

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I'm trying to follow a `Todo` app tutorial from Codepath (https://guides.codepath.com).

Source: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Todo-App-Tutorial

As far as I can tell I've followed the tutorial, but am getting the below issue.

```
Cannot resolve symbol `FileUtils`
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.codepath.simpletodo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView; 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    private ListView lvItems;

    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, items);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        items.add("Default item");
        items.add("Another default item");
        items.add("The third default item");
        // setup remove listener method call
        setupListViewListener();
    }

    // Attaches a long click listener to the listview
    private void setupListViewListener() {
        lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                                   View item, int pos, long id) {
                        // Remove item within array at position
                        items.remove(pos);
                        // Refresh the adapter
                        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // Return true consumes the long click event (marks it handled)
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onAddItem(View v) {
        EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
        itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
        etNewItem.setText("");
    }
}
```

**activity_mail.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvItems"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddItem" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etNewItem"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:hint="Enter a new item"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Item"
    android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="onAddItem"
    />
```

I'm extremely new to Android and would be so happy just to get things to work, as I don't have enough background yet to have any hope at debugging.

Any guidance would be very appreciated.

### UPDATE 1

**app/build.gradle**

*Original Format*

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codepath.simpletodo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

I've tried various combinations of including `'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'`.

1. Replacing `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'` with `'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'`
2. Putting both on same line: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0', 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'`.
3. Putting both on separate lines: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0' compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'`.

But when attempting the `Gradle project sync`, there is a failure with below message.

```
Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: compile org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
```

### UPDATE 2

The final working version needed to look like this.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
}
```

Comment: add your build.gradle code also

Comment: Added `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'` contains [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class. You should add this to your dependencies.

Comment: Where can I find such libraries list?

Answer (score 5):

I think, in your build.gradle following lines are missing

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```

Add above line to your build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

This worked much better for me for newer grade (3+) and dex files conflicts

dependecies {
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
}

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in 2022 is in the build.gradle file in dependencies add:

```
dependencies {
    (all the other dependencies that you have)  
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
}
```

Then, in the Activity.java import:

> import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

If I didn´t do that, my program imported another library that doesn´t have FileUtils.copyFile() but instead have FileUtils.copy()

Answer (score 1):

Version: Android Studio 3.4.1

You can click "Project Structure" and Add a Dependencies

Then you will see "build.gradle" file has a implementation line.

Or you just add a implementation line by yourself,

after you can click "Sync Project with Gradle Files" is also ok.

Finally, you should

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

---

[[image]
[[image]

Answer (score 0):

following Magali Sganga's tip, this is what worked for me in 2022 re-sharing as I was able to update and use the latest version at the moment

What worked for me in 2022 is in the build.gradle file in dependencies add:

dependencies {
(all the other dependencies that you have)
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
}
Then, in the Activity.java import:

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;