# how to use getFile() method in FileUtils android ? Cannot resolve method 'getFile' in 'FileUtils'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried the solutions mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417848/cannot-resolve-symbol-fileutils-in-codepath-todo-app-tutorial-android) but nothing is working for me.

I have imported the FileUtils `import android.os.FileUtils;`

I have included `implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'` in my Gradle build, not working.

I have tried with `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'`, still not working
I have synced the Gradle after adding the implementation in dependencies.

but it does not works for me.

then when I tried putting `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'` in my dependencies, the Sync results in Error.

What am I missing here?

Here is the relevant code :

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        fileUri = data.getData();
        File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

        if (fileUri != null && "content".equals(fileUri.getScheme())) {
            Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(fileUri, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            filePath = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            filePath = fileUri.getPath();
        }

        String absensiId = edtUAId.getText().toString().trim();

    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: You are most likely facing an import issue. Replace `import android.os.FileUtils` to `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` after properly importing the library via gradle.

Answer (score 1):

The way you import it now is:

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

Resync, and your `getFile()` should work.

Cheers.

Comment: that is what I'm currently using and it is not working to me

Comment: show your whole source code including the imports at the top of your file.